# Junit Testing Struts 2.x actions

Tags: junit, struts2

I have a simple Action class which I want to unit test:

```
package com.gam.action.test;
import org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase;

public class HelloWorldActionTest extends StrutsTestCase{

    /**
     * Test method for {@link com.gam.action.HelloWorldAction#execute()}.
     */
    public void testExecute() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

I've created this test case using JUnit wizard in eclipse. I get the following error when I run the test:

```
Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory
File: SpringObjectFactory.java
Method: getClassInstance
Line: 230 - com/opensymphony/xwork2/spring/SpringObjectFactory.java:230:-1
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:449)
    at org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTestCaseHelper.initDispatcher(StrutsTestCaseHelper.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.initDispatcher(StrutsTestCase.java:196)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.setUp(StrutsTestCase.java:182)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.getClassInstance(SpringObjectFactory.java:230)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyResultType(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:538)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addResultTypes(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:509)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:465)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:278)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:204)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
    ... 17 more
```

The problem is I don't know which jar files should be provided. I'm not using spring in my project but if I don't provide spring jar files I get some error and when I provide it I get this one. 
What combination of jar files are needed to simply run the test! (As you can see I've degraded my test method to a dummy method.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struts2-junit-plugin introduces its own dependencies, shown by this Maven output:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.struts:struts2-junit-plugin:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:compile
```

It *sounds* like you're not using Maven, which is almost certainly a Bad Idea. Managing transitive dependencies yourself is not terribly entertaining–save yourself some time and manual labor.